# Database Design: How to implement an "other" option?

Tags: database-design

I'm trying to design an application that will use a DB to store some information about boxes.

These boxes are located at a specific, predefined site such as "Garage", "Living Room", etc. Locations that could easily be chosen with a dropdown box . But sometimes they can be somewhere else like "Joe's" that would pretty much be specific and mostly non repeatable.

So my question is how to store this in the DB?
My first idea was to make a simple relation with a table with boxes

```
BOXES
| ID_BOX | ID_LOCATION | 
|  1     |      1      |
|  2     |      3      |
```

And another table with the locations

```
LOCATION 
| ID_LOCATION |  LOCATION     | 
|      1      |   Garage      |
|      2      |   Living Room |
```

But how can I put the extra options in here? Add them "temporarily" to the Locations Table? Or make an "Other" field and store this information somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these locations are sure to be pretty much unique and you do not need persistence once the object has been moved or deleted you could add an SQL function when deleting to check if there are any objects at a certain location, if there are non: delete the location.

If that sound dangerous or not a good idea (for most cases it will be a bad idea) you could add a column to BOXES to specify if the location is in a regular place or in a temporary place, create a table for each and make the relation in a 4rd table. This way you could only add the registers in REGULAR_LOCATIONS to your drop menu and add the 'others' option to write into TEMP_LOCATIONS

Or even better, you could add a column to the locations table and specify if they are regular or not, if they aren't you won't show them in the drop down menu. And you get to keep you r current scheme.

Comment: Interesting the approach with the regular vs fixed locations in the Locations table. It would even help if a batch of boxed would go to the same temporary location.

Answer (score 3):

I would simply have your current scheme where a location code in `BOXES` references a location in `LOCATION`, but *one* of those locations is "OTHER".

Then I would have another column in `BOXES` call `OTHER-LOCATION` which is used by your application only if the location is set to `OTHER`.

```
BOXES
| ID_BOX | ID_LOCATION | OTHER_LOCATION         |
|  1     |      1      |  NULL                  |
|  2     |      2      |  NULL                  |
|  3     |      0      |  On the 4:10 from Yuma |

LOCATION 
| ID_LOCATION |  LOCATION     | 
|      0      |   Other       |
|      1      |   Garage      |
|      2      |   Living Room |
```

It could be argued that this violates 3NF but I don't think so. The value of `OTHER_LOCATION` is still dependent on the key, the whole key and nothing but the key (so help me, Codd).

In this sense, it's exactly like those interminable forms you have to fill out where they give you a list of common choices with one of them being "Other", along with a box to fill out only if you choose that option.

Answer (score 1):

Just keeping it simple, yes add a varchar to the BOXES table called OTHER_LOCATION or something similar.  Then you can either allow ID_LOCATION to be NULL, or you can enter a specific Location row for other, and have your application code set the ID_LOCATION to that value, and require input into the OTHER_LOCATION column when it is used.  How you feel about the solution, depends on your feelings about whether or not you want to use nulls, and how you want to write your joins.  I'd probably recommend having the "other" row, perhaps as ID_LOCATION '1'.  Then you don't have to be concerned about inner joins between the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

I would add extra field to the *location* tabe with information if location is public or private (you can also insert user id or *NULL* for public). Then you can insert new value into the *location* table.

Another option is to remove foregin key and keep logical relation via *varchar* field values. In user interface you show values from the *location* table and save value provided by user directly into the *boxes* table.